# IF function within an IF function in Google App Script

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, spreadsheet

I'm not sure if this is possible or not, but I'm trying to achieve an if function within an if function using Google scripts.

My code is this:

```
function changeYears(sheet) {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var data = sheet.getDataRange();
var numRows = data.getNumRows();
var values = data.getValues();
for (var row = 0; row <= numRows - 1; row++) {
var stri = values[row][18];
if (stri.indexOf("Yes")) {
return sheet.getRange('E4:E').getValues()
    .map(function (r, i) {
        if (r[0] && r[0].indexOf(" ") > -1 && /\d/.test(r[0])) {
            var res = r[0].split(" ")[1];
            r[0] = "Year " + (res - 1);
        }
        return r;

    });
   }

}
}
```

The purpose of the script is to look at column S and check if there is a 'Yes' in that column. If there is a 'Yes' then it will look at row E and there will be a value from the list of 'Year 1', 'Year 2', 'Year 3', 'Year 4' and 'Year 5' and the script should change that value to 'Year 0', 'Year 1', 'Year 2', 'Year 3' and 'Year 4' respectively. (Only is there is a 'Yes' in column S) When I run the script I don't get any errors but nothing happens either. Any ideas?

Comment: `if` - not a function, also `indexOf` return `-1` if not found, so you need check it `stri.indexOf("Yes") != -1`

Comment: Changed it to that, however still just doesn't do anything when I run it

Comment: what is `stri`? are you try debug it?

Comment: var stri = values[row][18]; so its the values in the column S

Comment: If you mean what values can it be, it can be 'Yes' or 'No'

Comment: `sheet.getRange('E4:E')` what you try get here?

Comment: the range of values in column E which range from 'Year 1', 'Year 2'......'Year 5'. These are the values that need to be changed if there is a 'Yes' in column S

Comment: from E4 to what? are you sure you use correct A1 notation?

Comment: E4:E1000 (The whole of Column E excluding E1, E2 and E3) And im unsure as to what you mean by 'correct A1 notation'

Comment: i mean `sheet.getRange('E4:E')` can return empty, try `sheet.getRange('E4:E1000')`

Comment: There are empty cells in the range E4:E yes, would this affect it?, tried sheet.getRange('E4:E1000') but it still didn't do anything

Comment: i mean that `sheet.getRange('E4:E')` return empty range, so not any cells in this

Comment: `return sheet.getRange('E4:E').getValues()
        .map(function (r, i) {
            if (r[0] && r[0].indexOf(" ") > -1 && /\d/.test(r[0])) {
                var res = r[0].split(" ")[1];
                r[0] = "Year " + (res - 1);
            }
            return r;

        });`

This by itself works fine, its when i try to add 

`for (var row = 0; row <= numRows - 1; row++) {
var stri = values[row][18];
if (stri.indexOf("Yes")) {` 

is when it breaks

Comment: what is it?  you have same code in your post except E2 instead of E4

Comment: Sorry, it was an old piece of code that used to run it including rows 2 and 3, but it should start at 4 now

Comment: can you provide working sample? for example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?  if it not work inside `if` so `if (stri.indexOf("Yes") > -1)` or `if (stri.indexOf("Yes") != -1)` should fix problem

Comment: Ive tried both and neither work, also im not sure how i could use jsfiddle to produce a working sample. What i do have is this link of a sample spreadsheet which the script needs to work on https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hUFd4n6DsrDP9MXSRjEY8jCRpf2Yfjf_M2TRiR8e7kk/edit?usp=sharing , in the sample spreadsheet, if the code worked it would change the values in column E from Year 3 and Year 5 to Year 2 and Year 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't update cell value just assging value in values array, also you already in loop, you not need again loop on E column.
For updating value you should use [setValue function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue)

So you can reduce your code to something like this

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = data.getNumRows();
  var values = data.getValues();

  //start check from 4 row, row index started from 0
  for (var row = 3; row <= numRows - 1; row++) {
    var cell = data.getCell(row+1, 5);//get reference to cell in E column, here row index start from 1
    var stri = values[row][18]; //get value from S column
    if (stri.indexOf("Yes")!=-1) { //check that it contains 'Yes'
      var value = cell.getValue(); //get value from referenced cell in E column
      if (value && value.indexOf(" ") > -1 && /\d/.test(value)) {
        var res = parseInt(value.split(" ")[1]);
        cell.setValue("Year " + (res - 1));//set value to referenced cell
      }
    }
  }
}
```